# Find consecutive sum from Java array using loop

Tags: java, arrays

I need to sum of x element together in order from an array and insert the result in new array.
For example,

```
int x = 3;
int [ ]array = {1,2,5,8,4,9,4,2,9,7,5}; //we have 11 element here
int [ ]newarray= new int [Math.round(array.length/x)]; // the size will be round(11/3)= 4
```

The size of newarray will be 4

```
int sum = 0 ; // this will hold the sum of the array element
```

I need loop into array and sum the first **(x)**three elements and insert the summation in the first newarray index and empty sum variable

then loop again in the array starting from the next three element and insert the summation in the second index of the newarray and so on..

the last index of the new array will be summation of the last two element from array because there is only two element in the array
we get the some and insert it to the last index of the array the array should look like that

```
for (int i=0; i< newarray.length;++i){
    System.out.println(newarray[i]);
```

Expected output should be

```
newarray [ 0 ]= 1+2+5 = 8
newarray [ 1 ]= 8+4+9 = 21
newarray [ 2 ]= 8+4+9 = 15
newarray [ 3 ]= 7+5 = 12
```

Need a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to cast the `x` to `double`, because `int/int` will result in `int` so you will never get the space last for holding the partial sum. Use the `ceil()` function not the `round()`. Because `round()` converts the input to the closest integer, where as you need closet upper integer.

```
int []newarray= new int [(int) Math.ceil(array.length / (double)x)];
```

Use two loops and put the sum in array. First, iterates over the sum result array (where you are storing the sum) and second to fetch the element from the source array.

When the source array does not have element in the multiples of `x` make sure you don't access the extra unavailable elements, otherwise exception will be thrown.

```
for (int i=0; i<newarray.length; i++) {
  int sum = 0;
  for(int j=0; j<x && x*i+j < array.length; j++) {
    sum += array[x*i+j];
  }
  newarray[i] = sum;
}
// print the results
for (int xx : newarray) {
  System.out.println(xx);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try folowing code:

It can be done with reduced complexity having just the one loop:

```
    int x=3;

    int [ ]array = {1,2,5,8,4,9,4,2,9,7,5}; 
    int [ ]newarray= new int [(int) Math.ceil(array.length / (double)x)]; 
    int sum=array[0],k=0;
    for (int i=1; i< array.length;i++){
        sum=sum+array[i];
        if((i+1)%3==0){
            newarray[k]=sum;
            System.err.println(newarray[k]);
            sum=0;
            k++;
        }else if(i+1==array.length){
            newarray[k]=sum;
            System.err.println(newarray[k]);
        }
    }
```

**Output:**

```
8
21
15
12
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution you want,

```
int ind = 0, sum;
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i += 3)
{
    sum = 0;
    for(int j = 0; j < 3 && i + j < array.length; j++)
    {
        sum = sum + array[i + j];
    }
    newarray[ind++] = sum;
}
```

Now newarray contains what you want.

Comment: System.out.println (newarray [ i] ) give me that  8
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
 at test.test.main(test.java:23)